# How do I change part of an input value in python?

Tags: python, input

So if I make an input that is `function=input()` and I want the user to put in a function like `y=2x+3`. How would I change the **x** so that it equals one (without the user having to type it in manually) so if I print it, it would be `y=21+3`

I tried using global x then setting x=1 but that didn't work. (I'm pretty new to python so sorry if I'm missing something obvious.)

Comment: Could you please show your code attempt for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `x` in input string:

```
function=input()
# function gets 'y=2x+3' here
function = function.replace('x', '1')
# function now 'y=21+3'
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe so

```
>>> x = 1
>>> formula = raw_input()
>>> formula.replace('x', str(x))
```